# Call Rmath via Ctypes from Ocaml on OS X

Tags: r, macos, ocaml, dylib

I want to use R's mathematical functions as provided in `libRmath` from Ocaml. I successfully installed the library via `brew tap homebrew science && brew install --with-librmath-only r`. I end up with a .dylib in /usr/local/lib and a .h in /usr/local/include. Following the Ocaml ctypes tutorial, i do this in utop

```
#require "ctypes.foreign";;
open Ctypes;;
open Foreign;;
let test_pow = foreign "pow_di" (float @-> int @-> returning float);;
```

this complains that it can't find the symbol. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to open the dynamic library first? Set some environment variables? After googling, I also did this:

```
nm -gU /usr/local/lib/libRmath.dylib
```

which gives a bunch of symbols all with a leading underscore including `00000000000013ff T _R_pow_di`. In the header file, `pow_di` is defined via some `#define` directive from `_R_pow_di`. I did try variations of the name like "R_pow_di" etc.

Edit: I tried compiling a simple C program using Rmath using Xcode. After setting the include path manually to include `/usr/local/include`, Xcode can find the header file Rmath.h. However, inside the header file, there is an include of `R_ext/Boolean.h` which does not seem to exist. This error is flagged by Xcode and compilation stops.

Noob alert: this may be totally obvious to a C programmer...

Comment: There is also ocaml-r, a package which includes these bindings, but it's not on opam, so i am assuming it is unmaintained.

Comment: can you compile a simple C program, that uses librmath?

Comment: looks like, that brew package still have some problems. But for `ocaml-ctypes` you don't need headers at all, so it may work, since you have a library. Also, you may need to use the underscored name, since you're working directly with library, detouring the headers. There is also new stub-generating interface, that will use headers, and will not have this problems, but it will not work, since your installation is broken.

Comment: ok, thanks! i'll post an issue at homebrew i guess.

Comment: FYI, slides about OCaml-R are [here](http://files.meetup.com/1887771/2014-09-17_OCaml-R.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use external library you still need to link. There're at least two different ways, either link using compiler, or link even more dynamically using `dlopen`.

For the first method use the following command (as an initial approximation):

```
ocamlbuild -pkg ctypes.foreign -lflags -cclib,-lRmath yourapp.native
```

under premise that your code is put into `yourapp.ml` file.

The second method is to use ctypes interface to `dlopen` to open the library. Using the correct types and name for the C function call, this goes like this:

```
let library = Dl.dlopen ~filename:"libRmath.dylib" ~flags:[]
let test_pow = foreign ~from:library "R_pow_di" (double @-> int @-> returning double)
```

Comment: thanks, the dynamic import works for me now - even without the header! (after finding the right symbol name by trial and error) edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: actually, the coercion double to float seems to work automatically when used as input to a function expecting float. that's surely in the ctypes docs.